# Dynamically getting text from a textbox

Tags: c++, winapi, spy++

I'm trying to get text from other window dynamically( if I write something in a textfield of that window and then launch my program, I must see what I wrote ).So if I use getWindowText, it gives me a static initialized textbox.So that's the problem.It's similar ,what spy++ does. 
Here's the code example what I done:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h> 
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
HWND hWnd;
MSG msg;
vector<HWND> a;
hWnd = FindWindow( NULL, "SomeList" );
vector<string> phrases;
char p[100];
if( !hWnd )
{
    cout << "Window hasn't been found " << endl;
    _getch();
    exit( 1 );
}

hWnd = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_CHILD);
while (hWnd !=0)
{
     hWnd = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT);
     GetClassName( hWnd, p, 10 );
     string k( p );
     if( k == "Edit" )
         a.push_back( hWnd );
     GetWindowText(hWnd,p,100);
      cout << p << endl;
}
phrases.resize( a.size() );

for( auto i = a.begin();i != a.end();i++ )
{
    int index = 0;
    GetWindowText( *i,p, 10 );
    string n( p );
    if( n.size() != 0 )
    {
        phrases[index] =  n;
        index++;
    }
}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: When I launch my program it doesn't read the text, that I have written in the textbox, it reads the text, that has been staticly initialized. I need to read the text from a textfield, that is not initialized by SetWindowText, but from what I have written in a window

Comment: Is the edit control you're aiming for the first child of the window? If so you'll skip straight over it.

Comment: This's a test code, it's gonna change largely when i wrap it all up, but the question still remains.I've got test program, in which child window is edit control. From the program that is written above, I want to get dynamically text that is written in the test program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx) documentation:

> To retrieve the text of a control in another process, send a
>   WM_GETTEXT message directly instead of calling GetWindowText.

Example:

```
HWND hWndEdit;

[....]

char szText[ 128 ] = { 0 };
int cbCopied = SendMessage( hWndEdit, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)sizeof( szText ),
                            (LPARAM)szText );
```

Comment: That's not the answer to my question.

Comment: What question? To get the text of a window, one uses GetWindowText. You can't expect us to read in your mind. What's the problem?

Comment: This's a test code, it's gonna change largely when i wrap it all up, but the question still remains.I've got test program, in which child window is edit control. From the program that is written above, I want to get dynamically text that is written in the test program.

Comment: Gonna test that in some hours, I'll reply, when I add this stuff